# Linux from Scratch to bootable disk image

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, bootable, lfs

I competed LFS 7.6. I want to know is it possible to make it into a bootable disk image that can boot in to different systems?

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what your question is, however, I am confident that I can answer your question.  What you need to do is make an image of the partition that LFS is on.  I would assume that your entire LFS system is on one partition, and thus you can just make an image of your partition and then burn that to a DVD or a USB drive.
You would do something like this:

```
user@host$ dd if=/dev/sdaX of/home/user/lfs.iso
```

This will make a .iso file of your LFS system in your home folder.  You can then burn this to a DVD using a disk burner or to a USB using UNetbootin or by entering

```
user@host$ dd if=/home/user/lfs.iso of=/dev/sdbX
```

This will burn **lfs.iso** to partition *X* of sdb, sdb should be whatever your USB drive is.

--I hope this is helpful--

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux.  If you are unsure what the question is, but you are confident that you know the answer, then that confidence is hard to justify and may be misplaced.  That's especially true when you are new to the site.  If we were to go over to [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com), we could probably get a dozen or more relevant phrases, such as "Barking up the wrong tree," "A shot in the dark," "Still waters run deep," "Things are not always as they appear," etc.  I share your hope that your answer is helpful, but I do not share your confidence.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry for the way my response was worded.  I have made bootables for other, completed, operating systems, but I have never done it for LFS, so I did not know if it would be different, that is why I worded it that way.  Thank you for that information, however, and I will make sure to keep that in mind the next time that I post an answer to a question.

Answer (score 0):

Complete lfs, blfs and clfs then make it bootable or complete it on rewritable dvd. Then go to http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/SquashFS-HOWTO/ and understand what it says.

For install try to boot background and do quash commands for install in any system. By this you can get ur own install system.

ubuntu installation contain squash file system from which it install.

I think this will help.